How to make pipewire changes permanent
I need help setting up Pipewire to connect outputs to playback inputs consistently (meaning, always the same) and according to my specifications of what should connect to what. Pipewire changes things automatically if left unattended.
For instance, when I start a video on Chromium, Pipewire connects it automatically to the HDMI playback. I want it to connect automatically to the Analog playback, so I change it manually on the Graph feature of Qjackctl. But if I pause the video for about 10 seconds, the connection simply disappears and then I have to connect Chromium to Analog playback manually again.
This does not happen with Firefox. In Firefox’s case, the connections go automatically to Analog playback and do not disappear if I pause a video. This leads me to infer that there must be some config file where all automatic connections are predefined, but I haven’t been able to locate it.
I have Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and the kernel is 5.15.79-051579-generic.

This site allows 1 question per question. You have at least 2 here. Please correct. Also you need to edit the question and add the Ubuntu version info and make that super long sentence more readable.

Ok. I have edited the whole thing. Thanks.
